# Multi-site analytics tracking

Tags: xdb, multisite

We have a Sitecore multi-site, multi-server solution, exposed for the moment on the following domains: *www.mywebsite.com* and *lang.mywebsite.com*. We expect to add more site nodes in the current sitecore CM instance, so each would have their own *subsite.mywebsite.com* domain.

Behind the load balancer we have 2 different clusters (zone A and zone B, each with 2 servers). Basically we have 4 CD servers.

For now we set up the ***Analytics.ClusterName*** to be "*www.mywebsite.com*" both on CM and CD configs, as this is the main website load balancer host name. Is this ok? I have understood that ***Analytics.HostName*** must be left empty.

Is this setup going to track traffic analytics from *lang.mywebsite.com* or from the new to be added websites?